# Xtend - pop-off last character from template

Tags: xtend

I'm using Xtend template to generate list and I would like to pop-off the last comma from the generated sequence:

```
«FOR link : links»
«link.simpleName»,
«ENDFOR»
```

Can I manipulate the StringConcatenation behind "on-the-fly"?

```
«ENDFOR _builder.deleteCharAt(result.size - 1)»
```

The sample above is not possible, StringConcatenation does not have such a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Loops in templates](https://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html#template-foreach) support additional keywords to add characters before and after the loop and between elements.

You can use `SEPARATOR` to avoid the trailing comma:

```
«FOR link : links SEPARATOR ','»
«link.simpleName»
«ENDFOR»
```